# BigCommerce Single Sign-on

Tags: bigcommerce

We have created an app so that our customers can suggest product ideas to us via our Bigcommerce storefront. The app is iframed into our current site. In order to make a suggestion they must login and/or create an account. We would like them to use the same account they have already created in BigCommerce. Is there a way for us to handle single sign-on for customers via the API?

Comment: There's a template variable you can access to determine if the customer is logged in or not `(%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%)`, and read that customer's email address. Wouldn't that template variable be enough? You can transport it to your app iFrame by appending it as a url parameter to your iFrame target url. Make sense?

Comment: This template variable is something like a session variable, generated BC serverside IFF the customer is logged into the storefront. I think this should suffice for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Big Commerce have recently (August 2016) released their customer login API. It utilises JWT to allow a login to be integrated with an external system. I haven't tried this yet, but it looks promising.

see: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#customer-login-api

Answer (score -1):

BigCommerce uses oAuth, so it's possible to get the user's authentication via the [Load Callback URI](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/callback).

If the iframed App is on another domain, you'll need Cross-domain communication to make it work, or build an app that uses their [content scope](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/scopes).

Comment: It isn't possible to handle single sign on for a storefront customer through oAuth as there is no scope that provides access to the necessary information.

Comment: Yes there is, you receive the user id and the user email on the call-back. That's enough to be able to authenticate a user on the application's end (their site), and use it against a local DB.

Comment: You never receive a password, so you can't login the customer to make use of the account area or those functions. The customer still has to re-enter their password for other sites, thus multiple sign ons and not true SSO. It isn't enough to authenticate them with a user ID and email address as this can be insecure and not provide appropriate measures for protecting PII.

Comment: That's not how oAuth works, not even with google's. You receive an access_token that you can store and validate against BigCommerce. Then use that token to access BigCommerce's api form the backend or form a js client on the browser. On your own side, you create a user matching BigCommerce's id's, and assign a session cookie for authentication.

Comment: I'm speaking in context to SSO akin to what is documented here for Shopify: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/multipass

Comment: My point being that there is a lack of security on the storefront since it could be hijacked. We don't do HMAC signing of storefront responses. You can identify a customer based off of customer info from the api and match it to storefront variables, but you can't do cross-domain sign on securely unless you hijack account creation.

Comment: Agree, there is no way to sign in only once to both (SSO), but I don't think that was the intention, rather not needing to create a new credentials for the storefront. I don't see how this could be hijacked, assuming you have secure channels between all 3 parties. The sorefront doesn't need the responses to be signed, as it can validate the access_token against BigCommerce.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no token/other tool to facilitate SSO authentication with a customer account that exist within a BC store. The only way I've seen this done is with an external DB that basically hijacks the customer creation process and then submits a token as a password for that user on login pages.

Example: https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/social-login/